# Restarting MediaPlayer when connection lost

Tags: android, connection, listener, android-mediaplayer, interruption

Is the following code is right and sufficient for restarting the MediaPlayer in Android, when getting sudden stops of the HTTP MP3 live stream due to connection to the server lost or Internet connection lost/switching to other type of it? I will to restart player automatically when the connection to the server is lost. Will this listener handle such types of connection lost?

```
public void setOnErrorListener (MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener listener)
{
    if (this.mplayer!=null)
    {
        showError ();
        this.mplayer.reset();
        this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(currenturl));
        this.mplayer.start();
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest registering a BroadcastReceiver that listens for network events so that you can stop the playback when connection is lost and start again if it is reestablished. Otherwise, if the device is in a dead spot for a longer time, the battery may be drained by too many unsuccessful retries.

Like so:

```
context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

        if (noConnectivity) {
            stopMp3();
        } else {
            startMp3();
        }
    }
}, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

In your manifest, add the access network state permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I take this variant into consideration. But now I've realised version with Service and MediaPlayer, have no much time to refactor the code (if it's, surely, no much simpler). From the point of such possible errors, is my code right? So must I use namely this listener on stops or other one? It's possible to limit somehow the number of retries.

Comment: What you can probably do is listen for MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) - events. Then, `if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO)`, you can probably assume that there have been errors when connecting to the server. The code you posted does not register an onErrorListener nor listen to its events though. Of course you can limit the number of retries- just increase a counter every time you try.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any code examples how to create and register right this listener?